# Creating stacked pipeline profiles using water utility network tools?

Tags: geometric-network, profile, arcgis-water-utilities

I downloaded the water utility network editing tool to create profiles of our sewer and storm systems including manholes with elevations.

The profiling tool is pretty easy to use as you just click the manhole at the ends of the segments of interest.  The question is, can I stack two profiles to create a profile that shows both sanitary and storm pipelines?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  I'll try to take a look later, but just thinking about it I would say "probably not" as it's creating long-sections, and I don't see how you could overlay them when horizontally they may not actually line up properly.  Have you actually tried it?  Get the profile working individually for the two networks, then try running both at the same time.  If anything I imagine it would output two separately.